# Why golang show me "undefined" error on vds?

Tags: go, package

I use a package `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1` normally on my local machine. But when I put source code of my project to vds, copy also go.mod and go.sum, and run `go run .`, golang show me `undefined: secp256k1.DecompressPubkey` and `undefined: secp256k1.CompressPubkey`. I tried to reinitialize `go mod init <projectname>`. The go versions are the same on vds and on my machine. I am completely confused by this behavior, can someone explain what the problem might be?

Comment: Is cgo enabled? Do you have the c libraries installed?

Comment: @JimB no, I don't use c libraries

Comment: That package is a go wrapper around a c library.

Comment: @JimB oh, I didn't know. Then how do I enable it on the linux server? On my machine, I didn't use any special commands other than go install

Comment: Make sure you have gcc and all necessary  C libraries (helpers like pkgconfig are usually in some sort of generic build tools package)

Comment: Try this please: `CGO_ENABLED=1 go run .`